# Why doesn't linker produce multiple definition error here?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have a simple .h file like this:

```
//test.h
int x = 12;
```

If I include this file in ,for example, `main.cpp` and `functions.cpp` linker will produce this error which is reasonable :

```
error LNK2005: "int x" (?x@@3HA) already defined in functions.obj
```

But when I change variable definition :

```
//test.h
const int x = 12;
```

The linker error goes away . Way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A name declared at namespace scope that is `const` has internal linkage. That is, each file you include `test.h` into will have its own object named `x`. See §7.1.1/7:

> A name declared in a namespace scope without a *storage-class-specifier* has external linkage unless it has internal linkage because of a previous declaration and provided it is not declared `const`. Objects declared `const` and not explicitly declared `extern` have internal linkage.

Comment: @AndyProwl: mind=blown  (Yeah, I found it right as you corrected your answer)